# Leaflet - Check if polyline intersects polygon

Tags: leaflet, intersection

What is the best way to determine if a polyline (not just the vertices) intersect a polygon? Or checking if the polygon contains any of the polyline?

I am checking within a function where my polyline is an array of points like below.

```
var myPoints=[[42.414649077488, -71.13123893737793], [42.413286665076754, -71.13115310668945], [42.41220938779894, -71.13089561462402]]
```

If necessary I'd be happy to convert to a polyline feature like below before checking

```
var myPolyline = new L.Polyline(myPoints,{
        color: '#38c3de',
        opacity: 0.9,
        weight: 10,
      })
```

Comment: You can use either [leaflet.pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) or [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect if two polygon's bound are intersect

Example code:

```
if(rectangle.getBounds().intersects(polyline.getBounds()))
```